# Date format in Informix

Tags: sql, informix, to-date, str-to-date, string-to-datetime

Is it possible to print the `date` in the below format in `Informix DB`,

`May 19 1993 12:00AM` ?

Consider the below eg.,

If I shoot the below query,

```
select sysdate from systables;
```

It displays as,

```
2017-12-15 05:00:47.24318
```

But I want the output to be printed as,

```
Dec 15 2017 05:00AM
```

Comment: Cannot you use the [to_date](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/ids_sqt_130.htm) function?

Answer (score 3):

References on IBM Informix on-line manuals:
[TO_CHAR function here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1542.htm)
[GL_DATETIME here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.glsug.doc/ids_gug_085.htm)

```sql
select sysdate 
     , to_char(sysdate, '%b %d %Y %R') as _24h
     , to_char(sysdate, '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p') as _12h
from sysmaster:sysdual;


(expression)               _24h                                                _12h                                                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-12-15 07:47:04.0      Dec 15 2017 07:47                                   Dec 15 2017 07:47AM
```